# Laravel 8 Fortify Livewire Custom Redirect Redirect after Login or Register

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I am using Laravel, Jetstream and Livewire.

I have two user type. I want to redirect  after Login and Register to there own dashboard. How can i achieve this?

In older version i used something like this:

```
public function redirectTo()
{
    if (auth()->user()->is_admin) {
        return '/admin/dashboard';
    } else if (auth()->user()->is_authenticated) {
        return '/app';
    } else {
        return '/home';
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply refer this : [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVGHz9Hr1bU)

Comment: The SVG element itself is a square